# EdTech game development

Tags: game-design, gamification, educational-games

I'm creating an RPG / Adventure game with an educational foundation aimed at 7th-12th grade. I'm having trouble balancing quests and storyline with the foundational nature of learning.

Meaning, since this is a true video game, and is meant to immerse students in a game world, it's challenging to implement the necessary repetitive nature of education/learning while ensuring the game itself is not repetitive. So, if you have a certain concept/chapter you want to engrain into the mind of a student, how can you design seemingly non repetitive/non linear quests to encourage review of those concepts.

This question is inspired by my own interest to design an EdTech game, but also from Ted Talks like [Gabe Zichermann's How Games Make Kids Smarter](http://www.ted.com/talks/gabe_zichermann_how_games_make_kids_smarter) and [Jane McGonigal's Gaming Can Make a Better World.](http://www.ted.com/talks/jane_mcgonigal_gaming_can_make_a_better_world)

Gabe brings up several sources, like [Gamification By Design](http://shop.oreilly.com/product/0636920014614.do), but I'd like to know more sources that you can recommend that explain the components of an engaging EdTech game.

Comment: Please elaborate on the "trouble balancing quests and storyline with the foundational nature of learning" you are having. What did you try and what kind of flaws did you notice in your approach? Currently it is difficult to tell what you are actually asking. When asking about design ideas, can you at least narrow it down to the subject you want to teach?

Comment: @Philipp There's nothing difficult about it. Anyone who has ever had to come up with material and activities for classes will understand what the OP is asking. Essentially the question is as old as the teaching profession: How do I keep students interested whilst still relaying the necessary foundations in a given subject? - the only difference here being that the OP is now asking this within the context of e-learning.

Comment: @Growler ...Unfortunately, this question is very open-ended and will need to be closed as a result. I suggest you find a forum better suited to open-ended discussion within the context of games and/or e-learning. You can try gamedev.net and tigsource off the top of my head. Also, allow me to suggest that you look up the tag [procedural] on this site. Procedural generation of content, while potentially still limited, is probably key to a more random / varied experience that has a chance of keeping your students engaged.